# Pattern matching on TextBoxFor misbehaves in Firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validate

You can see a live example of my little ASP.NET MVC3/Razor app [here](https://myhealthonline.sutterhealth.org/mhoenroll/Enrollment).

The text boxes and textareas all have the following attribute to require just word characters. The form uses jquery-validate.js.

```
pattern = @"\w{1,50}" //50 characters, etc.
```

In Firefox only (v13.0.1) these fields are getting highlighted as if they are invalid when they include spaces, or characters like dots, both of which should be legit characters. Why just this browser and how should I correct it? Should I be using a different pattern?

**UPDATE:** I realized that it is the built-in HTML5 "pattern" attribute that is being handled differently by Firefox, which is why the form still submits OK.

Comment: Generally speaking, the class `\w` does not include spaces or dots.

Comment: Thanks, I checked on that and it seemed to pass in the regex checker I used. Should I use a different expression?

Comment: Try `"[\w\. ]{1,50}"` instead. Note the space.